# Change the amount of text printed in cells in Pandas with .head() method

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to print the full text of my dataset's values, using the `.head()` method.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Photo below of curtailed text in the `0` row.

[image]

Comment: The col width is set by default to 80 characters you can change this using `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)` for unlimited but this is not recommended

Comment: That question is more general but doesn't address .head() specifically.

Comment: The answer to that question is the same answer for yours

Comment: It is but I didn't find it on search and it wasn't clear to me that was true.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

Using a -1 there effectively turns off the column width. You can pass any length you want to instead.

From the documentation:

display.max_columnwidth sets the maximum width of columns. Cells of this length or longer will be truncated with an ellipsis.

Answer (score 3):

The currently accepted answer is now deprecated since pandas 1.0:

as per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#available-options), the `None` flag should be used instead of `-1`.

```
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", None)
```